# Telnet Server

Tags: c, telnet

I would like to implement a telnet server in C. How would I proceed with this? Which RFCs should I look at? This is important to me, and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: For fun, or for a homework assignment?

Comment: I can't say, but I think it is at least important to him...

Comment: If it is for practical use, it should be a SSH server...

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790367/what-is-the-final-rfc-for-telnet-protocol RFC 5198 is the current RFC

Answer (score 9):

For very basic telnet (just telnet to a port and echo bytes), there's not much to do.  Read from a socket, process it (in an echo server, do nothing), spit back a result.  You could implement a simple MUD-style server without knowing anything in any RFCs.

But if you're really concerned about RFCs, RFC 854 might be a starting point.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html

Comment: The question sounds like homework.  He got an answer that is suitable for homework.  What did you want to add?

Comment: Management of NVT terminal, escape sequences, etc.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. For basic telnet to work connection establishment (which involves option negotiation) has to happen. A bunch of telnet protocol commands have to be working before a server will get to stage of prompting user for login/password/commands. This sequence diagram shows what happens: http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/networking/Telnet.pdf

Answer (score 4):

If you are serious about network programming I would highly recommend Richard W. Stevens' "[UNIX Network Programming Vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)" - it's much better reading than RFCs with great examples.

It is very expensive book but there are cheap paperback edition available on eBay. Even if you get expensive hard-cover edition it worth every penny you paid.

Answer (score 4):

Note that real telnet is **not** just a simple interface that handles the `stdin` and `stdout` of the user's login shell.

There's lots of additional functionality that is carried separately in 'options', which handle such things as setting the `$TERM` environment variable, setting the rows/columns (and resetting them if the user resizes their terminal).

If you are looking to do *real* telnet, and not just a simple TCP server, then indeed RFC 854 is your starting point.  However there's stacks more relevant RFCs which describe those options mentioned above which are listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet

Answer (score 3):

If you need help with socket programming etc.

checkout beej's guide: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to watch the Telnet traffic using an existing Telnet server. Then looking at the log, you can gain a better understanding of how the server communicates with the client. Then, use the RFC as a reference if you don't understand any of the commands going across the wire.

Comment: This is extremely bad advice.   Read the RFC first and *then* look at Wireshark traces.

Answer (score -2):

Knowing how the socket API works internally is very useful, because it is often exported with very minor changes by higher level languages.

That said, you might want to use the event loop support provided by [GLib](http://gtk.org) and use the related networking library [GNet](http://gnetlibrary.org).

Here's how to use GNet to open a socket on port 4000, then close every connection made to it. There is a little bit of magic here as the server registers itself with the default main context as part of its creation.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gnet.h>

void client_connect(GServer G_GNUC_UNUSED *server, GConn *conn, gpointer G_GNUC_UNUSED user_data){
  g_print("Connection from %s\n", conn->hostname);
  gnet_conn_disconnect(conn);
  gnet_conn_unref(conn); conn = NULL;
}

int main(void){
  GMainLoop *loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
  GServer *server;
  gnet_init();
  server = gnet_server_new(NULL, 4000, client_connect, NULL);
  g_main_loop_run(loop);
  g_main_loop_unref(loop); loop = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```