# What is the final RFC for telnet protocol

Tags: telnet

What's the actual TELNET specification? I found [**RFC 854**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) which is very old.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [RFC 5198](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198.) is probably current. IF you look at the top of the RFC you referenced, there is a reference to RFC 5198 with a note that 5198 updates 854.

Answer (score 1):

854 is the last RFC for the protocol itself. NIC 15373 and IETF STD 8 are normative.

Several RFCs have proposed extensions eg RFC 1123, telnet over TCP. The most recent to specifically extend telnet was 4777, in 2006.

Answer (score 1):

The basic TELNET protocol has not changed significantly since RFC 854 was published (it was already a refinement of the TELNET protocol that was used in the Arpanet, prior to TCP/IP, so there were many years of experience with it). It was designed to allow for extensions using the `OPTION` mechanism, rather than changes to the protocol itself. There are many RFCs that describe options for the protocol, and RFC 1123 contains a number of clarifications and refinements to this (and other) protocols.

These days, TELNET is mostly an obsolete protocol. SSH has largely supplanted it, as it has built-in encryption and authentication (these are available as options in TELNET, but adoption is spotty).