# In User defined telnet server how to get telnet options provided by client

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In Linux machine 2, User defined `Telnet` server is running with listening socket on port number 6363. Whenever I try to execute the command below in Linux machine 1, `accept` call gets success and generated new socket descriptor at Linux machine 2. From here how can I get command line arguments provided by client(for example `-l username`)?

`telnet <ip address of Linux machine 2> 6363 -l username`

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [telnet protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) in your telnet server to get the options
provided by the client (i.e. it send it over the TCP connection).

For the username, you need to support [TELNET ENVIRON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1408).

See also this question: [Telnet Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267538/telnet-server)